# How to duplicate com.android.internal.R in my librairy?

Tags: android

Because of just one wrong written line of code in FloatingToolbar.java i was force to copy the entire source code in my library to patch it. This work but now the problem is that this unit call also com.android.internal.R. The problem with com.android.internal.R is that it's could be different between release, (because it's internal), so to be safe i must also duplicate the **definition**

in r class i have for example :

```
  public static final class layout {

     public static final int floating_popup_open_overflow_button=xxx

  }
```

where to find the xml (i think it's an xml?) that define floating_popup_open_overflow_button ? actually in \android-sdk-windows\sources\ i can find only the java files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where to find the xml (i think it's an xml?) that define floating_popup_open_overflow_button ?

You can find a copy in `$ANDROID_SDK/platforms/android-NNN/data/res/layout/`, where `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever you have installed the Android SDK and `NNN` corresponds with the version of the Java that you forked. There may be other variants of `floating_popup_open_overflow_button.xml` in peer directories (e.g., `layout-xlarge`); I have not checked them all.