# Where to find the definition of Theme_Material_Light?

Tags: android, android-theme

Their is something a little strange i can't understand. In the source code of android we can find reference to `R.style.Theme_Material_Light` but when i search in all the possible files the definition of `Theme_Material_Light` (in resources, etc) i can't find it. So where come from the `Theme_Material_Light` and where to find it's definition / implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

The `R` class is code-generated from resources, the same as it is in your project.

[As we discussed yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44273510/115145), you can find a copy of platform resources in `$ANDROID_SDK/platforms/android-NNN/data/res/`, where `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever you have installed the Android SDK and `NNN` is an API level of a version of Android that interests you (e.g., 25 for Android 7.1).

`Theme.Material.Light` is defined in `res/values/themes_material.xml`, at least for API Level 25's copy of the resources.

Comment: no, in res/values/ their is no file themes_material.xml :( this why i ask because i was unable to find it ...

Comment: @loki Yes, there is. If you don't have it you are probably looking under wrong platform folder.

Comment: @loki: For `Theme.Material` and kin, your API level needs to be 21 or higher. If you are looking in an older API level, there will not be a `Theme.Material` resource, as it did not exist back then.

Answer (score 0):

It's defined in android sdk (the fiscal resource could be found decompiling /system/framework/framework-res.apk)

Comment: but why it is not in $ANDROID_SDK/platforms/android-NNN/data/res/ like all the other resources ?

Comment: Yes you can find it even there. If you're using android studio use CTRL+B to go to code declaration/implementation

Comment: Sure all system sdk resources are stored in that path. The themes are in ../values-xx/styles.xml